# BreakPoints not being hit?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adb

I have been running and debugging my android app for quite a while now. All of a sudden I many of the break point I am setting are not being hit. I know the code is executed because of log messages.
I have noticed that once the breakpoint is passed for the first time eclipse adds a little check mark next to it..

I have tried rebuilding, cleaning and reopening eclipse... Noting helped..

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: So are you saying that during debug, eclipse never stops at the breakpoint? or are you saying that it only stops at the breakpoint one time? Does this happen in all of your projects or simply this one? Also, although you feel that the code is definitely being executed, would you be able to post a snippet of code and indicate the line you have a breakpoint set at. If you are not able to do that, I suggest that you place a breakpoint at a location above the one you suspect isn't working, then step through and verify inside the debugger that the line is being executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved by removing `android:process=":remote"` from the debugged code temporarily.

Answer (score 7):

Haha it's silly. My co-worker had the same problem when she showed me the top answer for this post. I am not sure how this happens or if this is what happened with you but if you click on the "Run" menu, you will see that "Skip all breakpoints" has a check on its left. Uncheck that and you are good to go.

Comment: That's one of the stupidest default settings I have ever seen. By default a new installation of Eclipse (such as mine) should be set to hit breakpoints. Gah!

Answer (score 2):

In eclipse, is the breakpoint marker a filled circle or an open circle? Try right-clicking on the breakpoint marker and click "Toggle Breakpoint" to enable it if it disabled, which is the only explanation I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is your solution, but this occasionally happens to me when my project has stopped building correctly after adding some code. You can check to make sure there are no Java project build problems by going into the menu options 'Windows' => 'Show View' => 'Markers' and check for 'Java Problem' errors.

You can also attempt to close Eclipse and re-open the application, I've had many strange Eclipse bugs remedied by an application or system restart.

Comment: Hmmmm nope, no problems there and restart didn't help